# Error when trying to update or get Entity with OneToOne relation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I am trying to make a `GET` request. I have a main `Article` entity and an `ArticleContent` entity. I have no idea what is the problem with the connection. When I am trying to get back the previously created entity the `ArticleContent` column is `null` (it should be the id of the `ArticleContent`).

This is the `Article`:

```
@Entity('article')
export class Article extends DefaultEntity {

  @Column({ type: 'integer', default: 0 })
  numberOfViews: number;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: ArticleType,
    default: ArticleType.BLOG,
  })
  type: ArticleType;

  @OneToOne(() => ArticleContent, { cascade: true, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  content: ArticleContent;
}
```

The `ArticleContent`:

```
@Entity({ name: 'article_content' })
export class ArticleContent extends DefaultEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  title: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  summary: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text', nullable: true })
  description: string;
}
```

How I make the `POST` request:

```
{
  "numberOfViews" : "13", 
  "type:" : "NEWS",
  "content" : [{
      "title" : "TEST"
  }]
}
```

What I see after `GET` request:

```
"content": null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that the type of `content` is `ArticleContent` which is an **obejct**, but you're passing an **array** to it in the `POST` request.